# Python Outside Error Function

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to calculate the euclidean distance by creating two vectors or lists having x,y coordinates as their lat long distances and have written the following code. But when running the code I am getting python return outside error function. Can someone help me out with the below code. Also if someone could provide a better code for euclidean distance would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

```
import sys
import csv
import numpy as np
# from scipy.spatial import distance
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
vector1 = [9.6, 32.4]
vector2 = [26.4, 27.6]
# vector3 = [8.4,25.2]
# vector4 = [3.6,44.4]
# vector5 = [27.6,3.6]
# vector6 = [37.2,46.8]
distance = np.linalg.norm(vector1-vector2)
print distance


v1 = np.array(vector1)
v2 = np.array(vector2)
# vOther = np.array(vectorOther)


def diff_Length_Error():
    raise RuntimeWarning("The length of the two vectors are not the same!")


def euclidean0_0(vector1, vector2):
    ''' calculate the euclidean distance
        input: numpy.arrays or lists
        return: 1. quard distance, 2. euclidean distance
    '''


quar_distance = 0
try:
    if (len(vector1) != len(vector2)):
        diff_Length_Error()
    zipVector = zip(vector1, vector2)

    for member in zipVector:
        quar_distance += (member[1] - member[0]) ** 2
        # return quar_distance, euc


except Exception, err:
    sys.stderr.write('WARNING: %s\n' % str(err))
    return -1, -1


def euclidean0_1(vector1, vector2):
    '''calculate the euclidean distance, no numpy
    input: numpy.arrays or lists
    return: euclidean distance
    '''
    dist = [(a - b) ** 2 for a, b in zip(vector1, vector2)]
    dist = math.sqrt(sum(dist))
    return dist


def euclidean2(vector1, vector2):
    '''calculate the euclidean distance, use numpy.dot() function
    input: numpy.arrays or lists
    return: euclidean distance
    '''
    try:
        if type(vector1) == list:
            vector1 = np.array(vector1)
        if type(vector2) == list:
            vector2 = np.array(vector2)
        diff = vector2 - vector1
        squareDistance = np.dot(diff.T, diff)
        return squareDistance, math.sqrt(squareDistance)
    except TypeError as e:
        print "Type error: {}".format(e.message)
        raise
    except ValueError as e:
        print "Value error: {}".format(e.message)
        raise
    except:
        print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
        raise


def euclidean3(vector1, vector2):
    ''' use numpy.linalg.norm to calculate the euclidean distance. '''
    vector1, vector2 = list_to_npArray(vector1, vector2)
    distance = np.linalg.norm(vector1 - vector2, 2,
                              0)  # the third argument "0" means the column, and "1" means the line.
    return distance


def euclidean4(vector1, vector2):
    ''' use scipy to calculate the euclidean distance. '''
    dist = distance.euclidean(vector1, vector2)
    return dist


def euclidean5(vector1, vector2):
    ''' use matplotlib.mlab to calculate the euclidean distance. '''
    vector1, vector2 = list_to_npArray(vector1, vector2)
    dist = plt.mlab.dist(vector1, vector2)
    return dist


def list_to_npArray(vector1, vector2):
    '''convert the list to numpy array'''
    if type(vector1) == list:
        vector1 = np.array(vector1)
    if type(vector2) == list:
        vector2 = np.array(vector2)
    return vector1, vector2
```

Comment: The error message means exactly what it says - you have a return statement, outside of any function.  Looks like you forgot to indent most of the body of ``euclidean0_0()``.

Comment: Can you like help me with debugging the error and post the code here?